# Profile disabled/not configured CiviEvent error

Tags: civievent

Getting this error when anonymous users or users not login in try to register for an event:

> The requested Profile (gid=17) is disabled OR it is not configured to
>   be used for 'Profile' listings in its Settings OR there is no Profile
>   with that ID OR you do not have permission to access this profile

I have tried setting ACL in Civi for anonymous to register.

Comment: Are you using Drupal as a CMS? There is also a permission in the drupal permission setting regarding profiles.

Comment: Do check `register for events`, `profile listings and forms` are enabled for anonymous users.

Comment: The profile lists and forms was the key to solving this problem.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: user21507 - You or @jitendrapurohit could add this as the 'answer' to this question then =]

Answer (score 2):

Following my comment, you get this error when you don't have necessary permissions of the profiles for anonymous users.

Required Permission -  `profile listings and forms`

`register for events` permission is needed if you get Access Denied on Event registration page.

More info on **Civi Permissions**:

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Default+Permissions+and+Roles

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Linking+Profiles#LinkingProfiles-PermissionsforProfiles(DrupalOnly)